# Setting the checked property does not get saved

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to automate a page which has a checkbox without proper locators. So, using executeJavascript to work on it. I'm trying to check/uncheck the checkbox using two different ways:

1. `executeJavaScript("arguments[0].click();",$(By.cssSelector("[id*='is-district-admin-check']")));`
2. `executeJavaScript("arguments[0].checked="+value+";",$(By.cssSelector("[id*='is-district-admin-check']")));`

   (value - true/false)

Issue is - when I have tried to save, 1st works. 2nd does NOT work - means it is not saved though the checked property is changed correctly.

Can anyone please give me some idea on this?

Comment: why are you using javascript as compared to native event? i.e. `element.click();`

Comment: I could not locate the element using locators. It always says that the "element should be visible" though the element is visible clearly in the UI